# Optimization problem - GlobalSearch is not generating initial vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, numerical-methods, ode

**INTRO**

I have to solve optimization problem, containing a set of ordinary differential equations. Whats more I need to find **global** minimum. So far I've only managed to find few local minimums, but examining manually which one is global is tricky for so complex problem.

**Description**

Let's say I have 3 Matlab files:

1. `Main.m` - its the general script file, which is a driver for all others
2. `ODE_set.m` - this hold all my ODE's system
3. `Opt_query.m` - this contain the definition of optimization objectives, and all equations needed to determined the minimum. Also from this file the ODE solver is started.

I can look for local minimum with this code, and it works totally fine, **without any errors**:

`Main.m`

```
global k1 k2 k3
x0 = [0.5 8 13];
lu =[ 0.9 25.74 60.9];
lb =[ 0.1 0.74 0.9];
[k,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon('Opt_query',x0,[],[],[],[],lb,lu);
disp(k1)
disp(k2)
disp(k3)
```

However as I mentioned above I need global minimum so I started to try with `GlobalSearch`. Here is my code:

```
x0 = [0.5 8 13];
lu =[ 0.9 25.74 60.9];
lb =[ 0.1 0.74 0.9];
gs = GlobalSearch;
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon',Opt_query,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,lu);
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = run(gs,problem);
```

It ends with **an error**:

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in Opt_query (line 3)
>
> k1 = p(1)

Here is the structure of `Opt_query.m`:

```
function q = Opt_query(p)
    global k1 k2 k3
    k1 = p(1)
    k2 = p(2)
    k3 = p(3)
    y0=[1 2 3]
    [t,y] = ode45(@ODE_set,[0, 130],y0,k1,k2,k3)
    t_steps=0:5:130;
    y_steps=interp1(t,y,t_steps);
    for j = 1:27
        Z = Z+ abs(y_steps(j,1)-5)+abs(y_steps(j,2)-7)+abs(y_steps(j,3)-9);
    end
    q = sqrt(Z);
end
```

Here is the structure of `ODE_set.m`:

```
function dydt = ODE_set(t, y, k1, k2, k3)

F = 20.1;
A_in = 2.5;
V = 100;
k = 0.150; 
A = y(1);
B = y(2);
C = y(3);

n = numel(y);
dydt = zeros(n,1);
dydt(1) = F/V*(A_in - A) - k1*A^2;
dydt(1) = F/V*(B) - k2*B^2;
dydt(1) = F/V*(C) - k3*C^2;
```

**The Problem**

So my question is - why when I use `fmincon` alone, it works fine, but when initiated with `GlobalSearch` it doesn't generate initial `p` vector which holds parameters to optimized? Did I miss something, or maybe `GlobalSearch` require different syntax?

Comment: You could try to debug the program, going through the program step by step with a breaking point at the failing line. For example the whole stacktrace of the error would be interesting. My guess is you should have written @Opt_query in createOptimProblem.

Comment: I've already tried as you can read in the answer section - without success. Just another error message. "Field name should be a character vector." or "Arguments must occur in name-value pairs." depending on the rest of the query (first if I just add @, second if I add extra parameters name in string form as suggested below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Few mistakes***

---

In `Opt_query` change this

```
[t,y] = ode45(@ODE_set,[0, 130],y0,k1,k2,k3);
```

to this

```
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)ODE_set(t,y, k1, k2, k3),[0, 130],y0);
```

> After `tspan = [0,30]` you should only use the initial conditions, do
>   not include `k1, k2, k3`

- Just take the function `ODE_set` which has `5 inputs t,y, k1, k2, k3`
  make a new one with two inputs  `t , y`then `k1, k2, k3` will be kept
  as fixed inputs

```
new_ODE_set = @(t, y)ODE_set(t, y, k1, k2, k3)
```

- Here is the syntax for ode45

```
[t,y] = ode45(odefun,tspan,y0)
```

`odefun` is a function of `t, y` only

- Since `new_ODE_set` is a function of `t, y` as well it can be used now as
  `odefun`
- but actually we still have `k1, k2, k3` inside it

---

```
for j = 1:27
   Z = Z+ abs(y_steps(j,1)-5)+abs(y_steps(j,2)-7)+abs(y_steps(j,3)-9);
end
```

> Here you should initialize `Z` to zero before running the loop, like
>   this

```
Z = 0;
for j = 1:27
    Z = Z+ abs(y_steps(j,1)-5)+abs(y_steps(j,2)-7)+abs(y_steps(j,3)-9);
end
```

---

> In `ODE_set` you're only using index `1` for `dydt`

Change this

```
dydt(1) = F/V*(A_in - A) - k1*A^2;
dydt(1) = F/V*(B) - k2*B^2;
dydt(1) = F/V*(C) - k3*C^2;
```

to this

```
dydt(1) = F/V*(A_in - A) - k1*A^2;
dydt(2) = F/V*(B) - k2*B^2;
dydt(3) = F/V*(C) - k3*C^2;
```

---

## To sum up

---

- ***`Main.m`***

```
global k1 k2 k3
x0 = [0.5 8 13];
lu =[ 0.9 25.74 60.9];
lb =[ 0.1 0.74 0.9];
gs = GlobalSearch;

problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',...
    @Opt_query,'x0',x0,'lb',lb,'ub',lu);

[x,fval,exitflag,output] = run(gs,problem);
disp(k1)
disp(k2)
disp(k3)
```

---

- ***`ODE_set.m`***

```
function dydt = ODE_set(t, y, k1, k2, k3)

    F = 20.1;
    A_in = 2.5;
    V = 100;
    k = 0.150; 
    A = y(1);
    B = y(2);
    C = y(3);

    n = numel(y);
    dydt = zeros(n,1);
    dydt(1) = F/V*(A_in - A) - k1*A^2;
    dydt(2) = F/V*(B) - k2*B^2;
    dydt(3) = F/V*(C) - k3*C^2;
end
```

---

- ***`Opt_query.m`***

```
function q = Opt_query(p)


    global k1 k2 k3
    k1 = p(1);
    k2 = p(2);
    k3 = p(3);
    y0=[1 2 3];



    [t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)ODE_set(t,y, k1, k2, k3),[0, 130],y0);
    t_steps=0:5:130;
    y_steps=interp1(t,y,t_steps);
    Z = 0;
    for j = 1:27
        Z = Z+ abs(y_steps(j,1)-5)+abs(y_steps(j,2)-7)+abs(y_steps(j,3)-9);
    end
    q = sqrt(Z);
end
```

Comment: Sorry but nothing changed, the error is exactly the same. But I found interesting thing: If I call `[k,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(Opt_query,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,lu);` instead of `[k,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon('Opt_query',x0,[],[],[],[],lb,lu);` I have the same error (not enough input arguments) even in single `fmincon`. So it looks like the problem is in how the `GlobalSearch` call `Opt_query`. An ideas how to solve it?

Comment: It is in separated `.m` file as I listed in OP. If I do `@Opt_query` it gives me `No field A exists for PROBLEM structure.` or if I remove 'objective' string from call it gives `Arguments must occur in name-value pairs.`

Comment: They are the same, I edited it here, to make names more clear. I keep it consistent in my matlab code. But it still doesn't works. I can't understand why calling `fmincon` alone works totally fine, while doing the same query through `GlobalSearch` fail. The syntax is not compatible between functions? If so it is huge mistake.

Comment: Ok. I editet OP, now you can reproduce it on your computer. It's not my set of ODEs so I'm not sure if it will find any minimum for this conditions, but if it will initiate without error - it is fine.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to works fine now. Just one part is not fully clear: "After tspan = [0,30] you should only use the initial conditions, do not include k1, k2, k3" What do you mean by this? k1,k2,k3 are required during whole calculation.

Comment: I added a short description just right below the statement you mentioned